# Conceptual understanding of how a battery ensures that a capacitor has the same potential difference as it?

Tags: voltage, capacitance, batteries, electrochemistry

I was wondering how exactly a battery is able to ensure that a capacitor connected to it would have the same potential difference as it.

Like, thinking about a battery similarly to a capacitor, I assumed that the potential difference of the battery could be represented by the integral of the electric field between the battery's terminals across the distance separating them. Which would be created by the charges that build up in the battery's terminals.

However, if you attached a capacitor and started moving the plates closer together/father away from each other then the charge in the plates would vary significantly but the charge in the terminals of the battery would remain constant.

But, in order to move the charges you would have to exert some net electric field on them which I don't see how the battery is doing, since moving the plates of the capacitor (assuming the capacitor is significantly far away from the battery) doesn't seem like it would have any effect on the battery itself that would cause it to exert some reactionary force on the charges on the plates of the capacitor to move them.

Comment: Moving the plates causes a current to flow

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the physical movement of the capacitors in some direction causes the current to flow in that direction by physically moving the charges, because otherwise, that is my question that I don't know how/what causes the current to flow.

Comment: Think of it this way: one plate has too many electrons and the other plate has too few. The only thing that keeps the extra electrons on the first plate is the attraction to the extra protons on the other plate. If you move them apart, the attraction force decreases, and the net force trying to repel the electrons will increase (ie. the voltage increases). If there's a battery connected, if the plate repels the electrons more than the battery does, some electrons will move through the battery and balance out again

Comment: Yeah, thanks actually this does sort of give a clearer explanation of what I've been thinking. The main problem I was having with this explanation was that the plates keep a (ideally) mostly constant electric field between them so the force pulling them doesn't exactly increase. But I did see with some simplified examples that even if the electric field doesn't increase there is still change in the net pull (sort of I'm not sure how to explain it well with words which is why I drew it out) that the charges on the plates exert on each other.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering how exactly a battery is able to ensure that a
> capacitor connected to it would have the same potential difference as
> it.

The battery has to do work to move charge from one plate of the capacitor to the other. The work the battery does per unit charge to move the charge between the plates equals the potential difference $V$ between two plates.

The battery can perform this work until the potential difference between the plates equals the battery emf. At that point the battery emf equals the potential difference between the capacitor plates and the battery is no longer capable of performing additional work to move additional charge between the plates. The capacitor is then fully charged.

> However, if you attached a capacitor and started moving the plates
> closer together/father away from each other then the charge in the
> plates would vary significantly but the charge in the terminals of the
> battery would remain constant.

The relationship between voltage $V$, capacitance $C$ and charge $Q$ for a capacitor is

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

The capacitance between parallel plates as a function of plate separation $d$ is

$$C=\frac{eA}{d}$$

Where $e$ is the electrical permittivity of the dielectric between the plates, $A$ is the area of the plates, and $d$ is the distance between the plates.

For a given plate area $A$ and electrical permittivity $e$ increasing or decreasing or increasing the plate separation $d$ decreases or increases the capacitance, respectively. That means moving the plates closer together while the capacitor is connected to the battery of voltage $V$ increases the capacitance.  So if the voltage across the capacitor is fixed at $V$, the net charge  on the plates must increase.

> But, in order to move the charges you would have to exert some net
> electric field on them which I don't see how the battery is doing,
> since moving the plates of the capacitor (assuming the capacitor is
> significantly far away from the battery) doesn't seem like it would
> have any effect on the battery itself that would cause it to exert
> some reactionary force on the charges on the plates of the capacitor
> to move them.

I'm having a little trouble following this.

The internal battery emf is fixed and does not depend on the capacitance of the capacitor connected to it (i.e., does not depend on the plate separation $d$). But changing the plate separation (changing the capacitance) will change the net charge $Q$ on the plates for the given emf.

In any event, the electric field $E$ between the capacitor plates is

$$E=\frac{V}{d}$$

So if the battery voltage is fixed, decreasing or increasing the plate separation $d$ increases or decreases the electric field between the plates, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answer. I actually had spent some time thinking about it and I think my issue was I was overcomplicating the scenario. I did a simple 4 charge set up (with 2 + and 2 - charges) arranged how you might arrange the terminals of a battery and a capacitor and connected the charges with straight wires and instantly saw where the electric field that was moving the charges was coming from. I was aware why it had to be that way due to voltages and capacitances I was just having trouble seeing exactly where the force that moved the charges to/from the capacitor was coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we quickly push the capacitor plates closer. There will be some resistance in the circuit (even if only the internal resistance of the battery), so charge cannot flow instantaneously and the charges on the capacitor plates will not at first change much. Thus the electric field between the plates won't, either – at first. So the pd $V$ between the plates will fall ($V=Ed$) below the emf, $\mathscr E$, of the battery. The difference between $\mathscr E$ and $V$ will drive current through the resistance, so the charge on the plates will increase. This will go on until $V$ is equal to $\mathscr E$.

Comment: But how does the potential difference by itself cause current to flow? Wouldn't there need to be some difference in charges that creates some net electric field that moves the charges from the plates to the battery? But I don't see how moving the plates of the capacitor changes/affects the charge in the terminals of the battery?

Comment: (a) "But how does the potential difference by itself cause current to flow?" It sets up an electric field in the circuit resistance that exerts forces on the charge carriers in that resistance, causing them to 'flow'. (b) I'm not convinced of the relevance of charges on the battery terminals. Thinking in terms of potential differences is usually more productive.

Comment: But how does the potential difference set up the electric field? wouldn't there need to be some difference/rearrangement of charges within the components of the circuit that creates an electric field causing the charges to move. And I'm considering the charges in the terminals because I'm assuming they would have to change in some way to create an electric field that moves electrons to/from the plates of the capacitor, but I don't see how moving the plates does this.

Comment: So I guess, after you pushed the capacitors closer, what charge rearrangement happened that cause an electric field to be created to move more charges to the plate. I guess it makes sense that there would have to be a field between different potentials but charges create electric fields which is sort of what I'm trying to understand/how it applies to the potentials created in the battery.

Comment: The re-arrangement of charges is done by hand, in moving the capacitor plates closer. This drops the pd between the plates ($\Delta V = Ed$) so there is now a net pd, $\mathscr E -\Delta V$, across the resistance. This drives more charge on to the capacitor plates and increases the pd between them until $\mathscr E -\Delta V$ has fallen to zero.

Comment: Well, yes, I understand if there is a potential difference created then there would have to be an electric field. I guess I'm just looking for an explanation in terms of the actual charges and how the rearrangement of moving the charges/plates closer together causes this potential difference to be created based on the electric fields created by the charges in the plates and the battery.

Comment: The electric field between the plates stays the same at first when you move the plates together, assuming that charges haven't had time to flow. This can be deduced from Gauss's law. The pd between the plates decreases because $\Delta V = Ed$ (which follows from Work = Force x distance in direction of force). I think I've said all that I can usefully say. Let's hope that someone else provides an answer more to your taste.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I guess I'll just add one more thing. One of the reasons this is concerning me is because say you had 2 very small capacitor plates that you moved very close together. This would result in a very large charge density on those plates. I don't see how the battery could be keeping the charge there assuming the charge at its terminal was very small/weak in comparison and the current could only flow through the wire. I would think that the charges would have a greater force pushing them to spread apart I guess.

Comment: My last words on this: if you want to understand how charges move in a circuit, you are shooting yourself in the foot by trying to make do with the concepts of charge and charge density, and not making full use of potential difference. A minor point from your last comment... using a capacitor of small plate area won't increase the charge density on the plates, because there'll be less charge on the plates (for a given potential difference).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I actually did figure out what I was looking for by simplifying the scenario (in a comment below). And yeah thanks for pointing that out, I guess I should have said large area since there would be a lot more charge on the plates pushing each other apart opposed a small charge on the battery, but even then I figured out that it wouldn't matter assuming idealized capacitors (i.e very close together relative to size/area).